# Is there an equivalent to $\|f \ast g\|_p \leq \|f\|_1 \|g\|_p$ on groups?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, locally-compact-groups

I'm new to Fourier Analysis on LCA groups and I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to the inequality
$$\|f \ast g\|_p \leq \|f\|_1 \|g\|_p,~~~~~\forall f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}), \forall g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}).$$

I couldn't find anything of the kind in Rudin's *Fourier Analysis on Groups*.

Answer (score 3):

There is an equivalent version of Minokowski's inequality for locally compact groups, namely the following:

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group, and let $1\leq p \leq \infty$. Suppose $f \in L^1 (G)$ and $g \in L^p (G)$. Then $f \ast g$ exists $\mu-a.e.$ and
>   $$ \|f \ast g \|_{L^p} \leq \| f \|_{L^1} \| g \|_{L^p}. $$

The proof of this result is primarily the same as for $G = \mathbb{R}$. The result is stated and proved in Grafakos' *Classical Fourier Analysis* as [Theorem 1.2.10](https://books.google.com/books?id=94FxBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA21).

Comment: I'd imagine the only potential snare is with a change in variables.

Comment: @abnry. I think the translation invariance of the Haar measure preserves a lot of the proof for $G = \mathbb{R}$. I am not aware of another proof for $G = \mathbb{R}$ than for general locally compact groups $G$. The proof is pretty straightforward.